# Coordinating graphic elements with streaming media

Tags: ajax, graphics, media, live-streaming, multimedia

if you were watching the State of the Union Address (http://www.whitehouse.gov/state-of-the-union-2013) you would have seen graphic supplements that appeared alongside of the video stream of the President that served to illustrate his key points.

The video on the site is a composite of this, but during the live streaming these were handled separately.

My question is: what is the best approach for doing this? especially if one wanted very tight control of the appearance of the graphics (i.e. right when the point is made, not before and not long after).

I'm wondering if any tools exist to facilitate this? I've been scouring google, but I don't think that I have the correct technical vocabulary for what I'm describing because I'm coming up blank.

I imagine AJAX would be a good starting point, but I'm not sure how to achieve the level of control that they had, or how to handle the back end of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might encounter this challenge we devised two ways to solve it:

**The first** is a bit mickey mouse: It requires that you know how many images, etc you want to use beforehand (which in most cases you would). We wrote a script to repeatedly request an image and inserts it into the page, and on finding an image then request the next image in the chain.

Ie. Display default image -> request image 1
then, displaying image 1 -> request image 2
etc

From your end you can simply drop the images into a folder on your server when you are ready for them to go in. An advantage of this is that the images can be interactive, with links to other content, etc.

The big disadvantage, of course, is a lot of unnecessary requests to your page. In our case we anticipated enough traffic that it didn't seem wise. Also, there are plenty of opportunities for mistakes and depending how frequently your timer fires there are likely to be timing discrepancies.

**The Second** costs money: we found the program Ustream (http://www.ustream.tv/producer) which allows us all the image control we require in terms of timing with the advantage of providing support for media clips etc. And it allows you to record everything streamed.

The disadvantage is that what the user sees is an integrated video on your site, so that you have to handle links to related content and provide images (if you want your users to have access to them) separately.

**Hope this comes in handy for someone**

I would still welcome any suggestions on how to make the first method more effective